# Shift-arrow keys send ABCD in Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash, mintty

My git bash isn't working. It's probably some setting I tampered with and I don't remember what it is. I don't know why Shift-left and Shift-right arrow don't select text but send D and C characters. Turns out Up and Down with Shift pressed also sends A and B.

The only thing I remember is changing the color scheme from dracula to mintty (as cli emacs selection color is the same as the text). My backspace also sends a space. Is there a fix (not a workaround). Here's my .minttyrc:

```
ThemeFile=mintty
Transparency=high
Font=Courier New
Locale=en_GB
Charset=UTF-8
Term=vt525
Language=en
OpaqueWhenFocused=no
ScrollbackLines=1000
Columns=100
Rows=1000
PgUpDnScroll=yes
ScrollMod=off
SelectionShowSize=12
ClipShortcuts=yes
WindowShortcuts=yes
SwitchShortcuts=yes
ZoomShortcuts=yes
AltFnShortcuts=yes
ClickTargetMod=off
FontSmoothing=none
BellFlash=yes
BellTaskbar=yes
ConfirmExit=no
CtrlShiftShortcuts=yes
AllowSetSelection=no
ClicksPlaceCursor=yes
MiddleClickAction=void
```

Edit: Changing the terminal "Term" does not help, it was something I tried to troubleshoot. Some other options are not default, but it worked correctly with them.

Comment: C'mon, why isn't anybody answering?

Comment: What have you tried changing `Term` to?  Does `xterm-256color` work?  `vt525`, while supported, is definitely not a good choice.

Comment: Well, I just reinstalled Git but using cmd as opposed to MinTTY as terminal because I get spoilt by the customization options.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Git like in a previous comment I made.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1110509)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue -- the ABCD behaviour appears (for reasons unknown to me?) to be the result of pressing `SHIFT`-`ALT`-`[arrow key]` in Git Bash. So in the OP's case, it seems likely their `ALT` key was accidentally stuck down (or otherwise registering as pressed).

(In my own case, it was due to some funkiness from accessing my PC remotely -- the remote PC keyboard's modifier key state somehow got out of sync from my local PC's actual keyboard state, so `ALT` and `SHIFT` were both silently registering as pressed. Rebooting the remote PC cleared up the issue -- there may be a more elegant solution to solve a bad keyboard state remotely, but a reboot was a quick and simple fix for me.)